# Reputation not correctly added

Tags: discussion, support

I have earned an upvote for an answer today.But I got only 4 points.

Is there any issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you earned 10 reputation for the upvote. Then you lost 6 reputation due to three deleted posts where you had suggested edits (losing you the 2 reputation on each post). That calculates out to a net total of +4.

You can find this information by [viewing your reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221895/don-chakkappan?tab=reputation) and making sure the checkbox next to "show removed posts" at the very bottom is checked.